# How to put together, using if or case, this statements?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have this statements and I don't know how to put together, using if or case

```
insert into tlp (given_name, namel, email)
   select 
       first_name, namel, mail
   from 
       glob
   where 
       (not exists (select email from tlp where (glob.mail = tlp.email)))
       and glob.mail is not null;

insert into tlp (given_name, namel, email)
   select 
       first_name, namel, mail
   from 
       glob
   where 
       (not exists (select namel from tlp where (glob.namel = tlp.namel)))
       and glob.mail is null;
```

Comment: What do you mean by put together. DO you want to make it as one insert statement

Comment: yes that I want to say :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to convert the two inserts into one insert then try something like this.

```
INSERT INTO tlp 
            (given_name, 
             namel, 
             email) 
SELECT first_name, 
       namel, 
       mail 
FROM   glob 
WHERE  ( NOT EXISTS (SELECT email 
                     FROM   tlp 
                     WHERE  glob.mail = tlp.email ) 
         AND glob.mail IS NOT NULL ) 
        OR ( NOT EXISTS (SELECT namel 
                         FROM   tlp 
                         WHERE  glob.namel = tlp.namel ) 
             AND glob.mail IS NULL )
```

Comment: @PopDaniela - yes you can

Comment: how ? just create a procedure, and put this script ??

Answer (score 0):

You can combine your inserts like this:

```
INSERT tlp (given_name, namel, email)
SELECT
    first_name, namel, mail
FROM
    glob
WHERE 
    NOT EXISTS
      (SELECT null 
       FROM tlp 
       WHERE
         (glob.mail = tlp.email or glob.mail is null)
         AND (glob.namel = tlp.namel or glob.mail is not null))
```